# What is the difference between red and green hard disk activity in Oracle's VirtualBox?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Here are some screenshots, so you know what I'm talking about:

### Red Activity

[image]

### Green Activity

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One is reading from the disk (green I think; the same color you'll see when reading from a CD or DVD), and the other is writing to the disk. I know I ran across this in [the manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html), but quickly skimming the table of contents and checking a couple sections I'm not finding it now.

Comment: And similarly, the Network Adapter icon can have Red dot for download and Green dot for upload :)